# How does docker run interpret dynamically generated --env arguments

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am trying to provide a dynamically generated list of `--env VAR1 --env VAR2 --env-file env.list` environment variables to `docker run`.

Unfortunately it is not working.

- for `--env` mapped variables, the variables are not visible in the container.
- for `--env-file` provided file, docker complains that it cannot find the file: `docker: open "env.list": no such file or directory.`

**Details**

Running:

```
# env_params contains either --env or --env-file arguments
MY_VAR=123
env_params='--env "MY_VAR"'
echo ${env_params} 

docker run -it --rm \
    ${env_params} \
    my_docker_image env | grep MY_VAR
```

will not output anything. `MY_VAR` is not visible inside the container. But:

```
MY_VAR=123
docker run -it --rm \
    --env "MY_VAR" \
    my_docker_image env | grep MY_VAR
```

will work and `123` will be printed.

In a similar way `--env-file` will not work when provided through `env_params` but will work when provided directly to the `docker run` command.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, When you run, in your shell:

```
MY_VAR=123
```

You have *not* set an environment variable. You have set a local shell variable.  When you use `--env MY_VAR`, you are telling Docker that you want to make the *environment* variable `MY_VAR` available inside the container, and since it doesn't exist you get nothing:

```
$ MY_VAR=123
$ docker run -it --rm -e MYVAR alpine env | grep MY_VAR
<crickets>
```

If you first export that to the environment:

```
$ export MY_VAR=123
$ docker run -it --rm -e MYVAR alpine env | grep MY_VAR
MY_VAR=123
```

Then it will work as you expect.  Alternately, you can use the `VARNAME=VARVALUE` form of the `--env` option:

```
docker run -e "MY_VAR=${MY_VAR}" ...
```

The second issue has to do with how shell variable interpolation works. If you have:

```
env_params='--env "MY_VAR"'   
docker run -it --rm \
    ${env_params} \
    alpine env
```

Then the resulting command line is:

```
docker run -it --rm --env '"MY_VAR"' alpine env
```

That is, the argument you're passing to `docker run` includes literal double quotes.  You can fix that through the use of the `eval` statement (keeping in mind that you'll need to modify your script to `export MY_VAR`):

```
eval docker run -it --rm \
    ${env_params} \
    alpine env | grep MY_VAR
```

Alternately (and I would argue preferably) you can use your `env_params` variable as an array, as long as you're using `bash`:

```
env_params=(--env MY_VAR)
env_params+=(--env SOME_OTHER_VAR)

docker run -it --rm \
    "${env_params[@]}" \
    alpine env | grep MY_VAR
```

Which would result in the correct command line:

```
docker run -it --rm --env MY_VAR --env SOME_OTHER_VAR alpine env
```

I guess the summary here is that your issues ultimately have nothing to do with "how `docker run` interprets dynamically generated arguments", but have everything to do with "how shell variables and interpolation work".

Comment: :) nice! Checking it all now.

Comment: Thanks! Both the array solution and removing the extra quoted around `MY_VAR` in `env_params='--env "MY_VAR"'` fixed the solution. The variable export in my case was not the issue since I receive them from the environment (I just did the mistake when simplifying the example). Thanks!