# Variable substitution in docker-compose .yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was trying to use [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) for a volume declaration. This led to the fallowing error:

```
ERROR: for php  Cannot create container for service php: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
```

Docker's Compose file:

```
services:        
  php:
      image: php5-apache-composer
      volumes:
        - ${DIR}:/var/www/html
```

Is variable substitution supported for the volume declaration? I can use environment variables for any other declaration except this one.

Comment: You are using the latest version of `docker-compose`? If so then it should have worked, if it doesn't then you should report it as a bug

Comment: How are you setting the `DIR` variable?

Comment: @larsks I run `DIR="/var/www/html"` before `docker-compose`.

Comment: Does the first part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808374/147356 help out?

Comment: @larsks , I've run `export DIR="/var/www/html"` and  `sudo docker-compose  run php -e DIR="/var/www/html"` and got the same error.

Comment: @TarunLalwani , docker-compose version 1.19.0, build 9e633ef - the latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [.env](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) file in folder where `docker-compose.yaml` is in order to declaring default environment variables for `docker-compose.yaml` file.

Just create `.env` file with the following content:

```
DIR=/var/www/html
```

Of course you can do that dinamically on each build like:

```
echo "DIR=/var/www/html" > .env && docker-compose up
```

Comment: Despite you forgot to run docker-compose as root, it works.

Answer (score 2):

> I've run `export DIR="/var/www/html"` and `sudo docker-compose run php -e DIR="/var/www/html"`

The `sudo` creates a different environment for the command it's running, the `DIR` variable doesn't exist there. You can check that with a simple `env` command:

```
$ export USER_VAR=test
$ sudo env | grep USER_VAR
$
```

To get this to work, you'll need to either:

1. Create a `.env` and let `docker-compose` source the variable from that.
2. Run a shell with `sudo -s` and run both commands as root from there.
3. Run a shell as the sudo command, e.g.: `sudo /bin/sh -c "DIR=/var/www/html docker-compose run php -e DIR=/var/www/html"`